# Initiate application profiling from code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way we can initiate application [profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb385749.aspx) from code for .Net applications (WPF). That means without having to run it explicitly from Visual Studio.

Comment: Web, WPF or WinForms?

Comment: have updated the original question to WPF - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Perfmon.exe` with command line arguments

[Command-Line Options for Faster Access to Performance Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff723776.aspx)

OR

You can use [Performance Counter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t90y2y1%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316365) is an article on using Performance Counter Class